# Eclipse + ADT - Autocomplete in @string/ references in layout files

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

When I am editing a layout file is there a way to get eclipse to autocomplete my strings references from strings.xml.

For example if I have a layout node like this...

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/settings_category_stay_intouch_title">
```

It would be great if I could type the `@string/settings_ part` and then use alt+space like I can when I referencing the R.string in a source file.

Right now I just get "No XML Template Proposal"

Any tips for configuration or plugins would be appreciated. I use strings.xml extensively and I have a ton of layout files so flipping back and forth between strings.xml and my layouts as I work on them is a bummer.

Comment: For whatever weird reason my xml had lost it's association as being a resource file. Fixed by right click "open with -> android xml resources".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it should work. Try using on windows CTL+space.

I tested with latest ADT 16.

Comment: For whatever weird reason my xml had lost it's association as being a resource file. Fixed by right click "open with -> android xml resource

Comment: yes thanks just knowing it should be working was helpful. Once I opened with android xml resource it seems to have stuck.